# In Visual Studio 2010, how can I tell what strings are visible to the user, and what strings are not?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, backend, frontend

I have a lot of hardcoded strings in a large application, and I need to know which strings are front-end (visible in the GUI), and which are back-end (i.e. sorting parameters) so I can edit them accordingly.

Is there any easy way to tell the difference? At the moment, I have to decide between doing everything the safe way but wasting a bunch of time, or saving time but running the risk that the application won't work the way I want it to.

Edit: The application is mostly form-based. By strings I mean anything in the code that is literally a string. Some are obviously meant for the user, such as error messages, but some are not so obvious, such as "customer". I don't know if "customer" is something that pops up on a dialog box somewhere or if it's something totally internal.

Comment: Could you please provide more information, what strings? what is the type of the application? web, mobile, form ?

Comment: Why are you using strings for sorting parameters? It seems like to me you should be refactoring small bits of the code a little bit at a time, replacing those magic string literals with enums. Everything that is left is therefore visible to the user, and should probably be loaded from a localizable resource.

Comment: Cody Gray - This is a large application that people have been working on for years. I didn't make the call to use strings as sorting parameters. There are some things that were done that are bad practice, and I've been tasked with cleaning it all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no easy way.

My Suggestion: You could start by writing some scripts to detect strings consumed by dialogs/ux/console and fix these. Then you should exclude things like traces/logging etc. If you find further patters use those to finally end up with a smaller subset of items that you would have to manually prune out.

This mess is difficult to clean up, especially so for a larger application.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly, I think I just figured this out, and the solution is mind-bogglingly simple.

When you hover the mouse over a string, the dialog should say "localizeable string" for something in the GUI, and "class String System.String" for internal stuff. At least, that's how I'm interpreting it. I wish I had noticed this before posting the question...

EDIT: This is NOT always true.